# Can not Autowired in SpringBoot project

Tags: java, spring-boot

All programs are here.
https://github.com/horitaku1124/spring_batch_sample/tree/master/SpringBatchSample1

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        {
            JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean("jobLauncher", JobLauncher.class);
            Job job = context.getBean("myJob1", Job.class);

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Job Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

MyBatchJob.java

```
public class MyBatchJob implements Tasklet {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("MyBatch");

    @PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private SampleTableRepository sampleTableRepo;

    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution arg0, ChunkContext arg1)
            throws Exception {
        SampleTableEntity sampleTable = new SampleTableEntity();
        sampleTable.setName("test name");
        sampleTable.setStatus(100);
        entityManager.persist(sampleTable);

        sampleTableRepo.findAll();

        System.out.println("Created SampleTableEntity=" + sampleTable.getId());
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

Execute this Main.java and I got this error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.example.spring.repository.SampleTableRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

EntityManager works well.
But I got error when Autowired SampleTableRepository.
How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should defined your repository in your application-context, otherwise Spring cannot find it.

Comment: I added this property  
`<jpa:repositories base-package="com.example.spring.repository.*"/>`  
But I got another error.  
`Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 34; columnNumber: 70; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'jpa:repositories'.`  
How should I fix this issue?